# How to copy an array that has been initialized as an smartpointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, smart-pointers

I am using `std::unique_ptr<uint8[]> CPPPixelBuffer;` to store pixel data of a texture as an array.

This array is initialized in the constructor as followed:

```
SIZE_T BufferSize = WorldTextureWidth * WorldTextureHeight * DYNAMIC_TEXTURE_BYTES_PER_PIXEL;
CPPPixelBuffer = std::make_unique<uint8[]>(BufferSize);
```

The creation and drawing of the texture is working so far. (as shown on the picture below)
[TextureData as the are supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1RLQ.png)

Now I am trying to create a copy of that array using a for loop. (I am using a for loop because I want to extract just parts of the texture later on. But just for demonstration I copy the array completly in this example.)

```
SIZE_T PartBufferSize = WorldTextureWidth * WorldTextureHeight * DYNAMIC_TEXTURE_BYTES_PER_PIXEL;
std::shared_ptr<uint8[]> PartPixelBuffer(new uint8[PartBufferSize]());

// Get the base pointer of the pixel buffer
uint8* Ptr = CPPPixelBuffer.get();

//Get the base pointer to the new pixel buffer
uint8* PartPtr = PartPixelBuffer.get();

for (int i = 0; i < WorldTextureHeight *WorldTextureWidth * DYNAMIC_TEXTURE_BYTES_PER_PIXEL; i++) {

        *(PartPtr++) = *(Ptr++);
}

delete Ptr;
delete PartPtr;
```

The pixels after copying are mixed up and the picture is different every time I execute this code. (as shown on the picture below)
[Wrong Reults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06liO.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't explicitly delete pointers that are owned by smart pointers

Comment: On the other hand, a mandatory question: why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: I am thinking it would be more efficient to use an array with fixed size than a dynamic array (or vector).

Comment: why do you think so ? Maybe it is faster, but before you profiled and measured, this is really just [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: *'I am thinking it would be more efficient'*, so much bad code starts with this thought. Write the code the simple way first, then see if you have an efficiency problem, very often you won't, but if you do, then improve the code you have already written.

Comment: This code *screams* that it should be using `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`.

Comment: BTW you don't need to deal with raw data here at all. The smart pointers support subscript operators just fine: `PartPixelBuffer[i] = CPPPixelBuffer[i];`

Comment: Thank you... I have just tried `PartPixelBuffer[i] = CPPPixelBuffer[i];` but the behavior remains the same :(

Comment: Not using `std::vector` would be (marginally) faster *if you didn't perform dynamic allocation anyway!* As it stands, you are emulating a vector which makes little sense ;-).

Comment: It also feels wrong to first create smart pointers and then extract the raw pointers for operations *that you implement yourself.* (I think the main reason get() exists at all is to serve cases like *existing* library functions which are old and don't know better than to take raw pointers.) If you need to pass the pointer around in your own code, use shared pointers.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you guys. I am going to try it with a vector. Just to explain: I am using Java and Python for 10 years now and want to learn a new language. Thats also one reason I tried the smartpointer. Vectors are just as in Java ^^'

Comment: But just for the record: It should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: knowing java and python is not a big advantage when you want to learn C++. You basically have to unlearn everything. Among those three Java and python have some commonalities, while C++ is completely different. Don't get fooled by similar looking syntax

Comment: in the code you just added in the last loop you increment the pointer twice in each iteration. Already in the second iteration you are out of bounds. Please do not alter the question to ask about something else or about an error in different code after you received answers already

Comment: if you remove the addtional increment you get expected output : https://godbolt.org/z/cs9rhbYKo

Comment: and you can get the same without any manual pointer arithmetic https://godbolt.org/z/Mdvo3oYTh

Comment: Ah...yes... you are right. That does explain this. i am going to delet this edit than.

Comment: what you're doing wrong is deleting the array and the copy.

Answer (score 2):

The last two lines are triple wrong.

1. the arrays are managed by smart pointers. You should not `delete` them manually.
2. the arrays are created via `new[]`. Freeing the memory would need `delete[]`
3. the pointers are not pointing to the beginning of the array, because they have been incremented in the loop

Each point alone would cause undefined behavior.

You should remove the last two lines. It is unclear why you think you would need to detele the original and the copy after copying the data. The copying itself looks ok (though there are simpler way to copy the array as mentioned in comments).

Comment: Thank you. I have suspected that I need to "reset" the pointer after incrementing so I get the pointer pointing to the start of the array calling CPPPixelBuffer.get(). But how do I do this?

Comment: " have suspected that I need to "reset" the pointer after incrementing " why? Thats not what I said.

Comment: @Schrello the pointer to beginning of the array is `CPPPixelBuffer.get()` also after the loop

Comment: But why is the result different every time I am executing this code? It seems that the pointer starts at different points every time. I also tryied `std::copy(CPPPixelBuffer.get(), CPPPixelBuffer.get() + PartBufferSize, PartPixelBuffer.get());`. And after that even the picture held in the original array has changed.

Comment: because when your code has undefined behavior then anything can happen, everytime you run the code.

Comment: @Schrello you might have other issues in code you did not post. But those two lines are definitiely reason enough to get any unpredictable output, while the rest of the code you show looks okish

Comment: I am going to remove those two lines. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Schrello if the answer helped with your issue, don't forget to accept and upvote it

Comment: It did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Schrello you might have other issues in code you did not post.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you use arrays that managed by smartpointers. This means, that you don't need to call `delete` to free memory, these pointers will be freed when they will be out-of-scope.
Secondly, while coding in C++, use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays, because it has some advantages like better safety.
Thirdly, if you use smartpointers, then do **not** allocate memory explicitly, use functions that will do that for you. In your case, you might want to use `std::make_shared<>()`.
This is example of code, where I create one smartpointer to `std::vector`, that stores `uint8_t`, and after that, I copy that pointer to another pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    auto ptr1 = std::make_shared<std::vector<uint8_t>>();
    auto ptr2 = ptr1;

    std::cout << ptr1 << '\n';
    std::cout << ptr2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This will print addresses of memory which smartpointers are pointing to. Note that every run of program you will see different memory addresses, but these two addresses will be the same.
If you want to copy array when using smartpointers, you can do this trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    auto ptr1 = std::make_shared<std::vector<uint8_t>>();
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec = *ptr1;

    std::cout << ptr1 << '\n';
    std::cout << &vec << '\n';

    

    return 0;
}
```

This trick will let you to copy array. When running that code, array which is pointed by `ptr1` and `vec` will be equal, but with different memory addresses.